# Oracle11g Spooling issue

Tags: oracle11g, spool

When I enter SPOOL c:\filename I am getting error:

```
SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file.
```

I have searched but nothing works. I am trying to output the file to the c drive. The disk is not full and it does have write permission.

Comment: That's literally what you are using, not a longer path to a file name (e.g. with spaces in it)? Which client are you running this on - and just to rule out the obvious, the client is running on the same PC? Not on another machine or in a VM running on that PC, say?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, that is the file path. I have also tried a longer path to my desktop and still get the issue. I am running this on my Windows 8 machine no vm.

Answer (score 0):

When I right click in the C drive directory to make a new document I was getting a permission error (was a windows popup error). So I knew there was something wrong permission wise in that drive. So I created a new folder within the C drive and was able to output the file to there.

Comment: So the statement "it does have write permission" in your question wasn't correct?